Unable to deploy Bitnami helm
I´m having some issues with my Talos Linux cluster.
I´m currently running 2 machines (1 controlplane and 1 worker) on Virtualbox, both machines have 4GB of ram and 4 cpu units. I also have a TrueNas server to provide NFS shares, nfsv4 is enabled on TrueNas and the share is accesible on other linux machines (tested on ubuntu 20.04 and Kali Linux).
All the machines have conectivity. I´ve installed NFS-CSI driver as the Kubernetes doc suggest. I´m trying to deploy wordpress helm chart from bitnami, and I get this error:
 Error: failed to create subPath directory for volumeMount "wordpress-data" of container "wordpress"

The NFS share its setted with 777 permisions. What you think it could be?

After doing an intensive research, the problem was related the configuration of the NFS service on TrueNas, so I changed for a nfs-kernel-server and now is working perfectly
